# Unity Involve Instatiated objects in Animation

Tags: animation, 2d, instantiation, unity-game-engine

In the 2d-game the player should be able to shovel some dirt when he stands on a dirtpile. player allready has the animation for that, but the shovel has to be generated.

So i generate the shovel and trigger the animation. but the animator doesn't animate the shovel. Any solutions?

Comment: Update your question or it'll be closed because is "too board"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i found the answer my self. before Triggering the animation event Rebind the Animator.

```
 Animator anim = player.GetComponent<Animator>();
 anim.Rebind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does the shovel need to be generated? If you just want it to be visible at certain times, you can go ahead and animate it normally in the Editor, then set it to inactive when you don't want it to be there.

Comment: it was more of a general thing i wanted to do, like giving the player different weapons, afterwards they should be animated